# WatchKit : connect 2 sliders to 1 label

Tags: swift, slider, label, watchkit, watchos

`tenSlider` is going to change the `currentBPM` value by 10 and pass its result to bpmLabel. This works fine.

However, I also want the `onesSlider` update that same label, but instead by +1 or -1.

The problem is that it doesn't check the current value and update that value. Instead it just updates its own value and passes it to the `bpmLabel`.

Anyone know how to connect the two?

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {


@IBOutlet var bpmLabel: WKInterfaceLabel!

@IBOutlet var tenSlider: WKInterfaceSlider!
@IBOutlet var onesSlider: WKInterfaceSlider!

var currentBPM = Int()

@IBAction func tenSliderDidChange(value: Int) {
    currentBPM = value
    updateLabel()
}



@IBAction func onesSliderDidChange(value: Int) {
    currentBPM = value
    updateLabel()

}

func updateLabel() {
    bpmLabel.setText("\(currentBPM)")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're always changing the currentBPM value to the value that is set by the slider. So if you set the ones slider the currentBPM value contains the values for one slider and same thing for tens. Since you can't access the value from sliders directly I suggest going this way:

```
var ones = Int()
var tens = Int()
var currentBPM: Int {
    return tens * 10 + ones
    // return tens + ones - depending on how did you set the min, max and step values on the ten slider
}

@IBAction func tenSliderDidChange(value: Int) {
    tens = value
    updateLabel()
}



@IBAction func onesSliderDidChange(value: Int) {
    ones = value
    updateLabel()

}

func updateLabel() {
    bpmLabel.setText("\(currentBPM)")
}
```